# EasyHook Inject - ArgumentException "The given 32-bit library doesn't exist"

Tags: c#, dll, gac, 32-bit, easyhook

I'm trying to inject a dll using EasyHook's

```
RemoteHooking.Inject(pid, InjectionOptions.Default, debug_dllPath_32, debug_dllPath_64, channel);
```

Unfortunately this throws an ArgumentException "STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_4: The given 32-Bit library does not exist! (Code: 2)" although im 100% sure the path is correct and that the dll referenced is a 32-bit library (Platform Target: x86)

Before that I register the dll's in the GAC using

```
Config.Register("desc", debug_dllPath_32, debug_dllPath_64);
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because EasyLoad32/64.dll are not correctly present.

---

Now this is pretty easy to solve

- Install EasyLoad32/64.dll in GAC
- include EasyLoad32/64.dll in application directly

Please feel free to ask any questions you might have.

Edit: Found same question here, [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431400/easyhook-resolve-status-invalid-parameter-4-the-given-32-bit-library-does-not/31732773#31732773)

Comment: I added the paths to EasyLoad32.dll and EasyLoad64.dll to the Config.Register call and tried to install them to the GAC using gacutil.exe but the problem still occurs

Comment: After reading another post I found out that it works perfectly fine if you just don't call Config.Register and don't register the the assemblies to the GAC at all, still thanks for the effort